# grepl not searching correctly in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to search ".com" in a vector, but grepl isn't working out for me. Anyone know why? I am doing the following

```
vector <- c("fdsfds.com","fdsfcom")
grepl(".com",vector)
```

This returns

```
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

I want it to strictly refer to "fdsfds.com"

Comment: Ah it requires two "\\" not just one "\". Got it thanks!

Comment: How do you escape a "\"? It doesn't work with fixed=TRUE.

Answer (score 6):

As @user20650 said in the comments above, use `grepl("\\.com",vector)`. the dot (`.`) is a special character in regular expressions that matches any character, so it's matching the second "f" in "fdsfcom".  The `"\\"` before the `.` "escapes" the dot so it's treated literally.  Alternatively, you could use `grepl(".com",vector, fixed = TRUE)`, which searches literally, not using regular expressions.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to search for a "/"?

Comment: You can search for a `/` literally, it's not a special character. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html